# Laravel Nova 4 : How to combine Full Name = First Name + Last Name in laravel Nova 4? in view or in model

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

This example code in field :

```
  public function fields(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [
            Text::make('first_name')->required(),
            Text::make('last_name')->required(),
        ]
    }
```

Full Name = First Name + Last Name before save to DB

Comment: use mutator in your model class